# ListLinePlot with shading areas

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a time series plot, and would like to shade specific regions in light grey (transparent) like this [image]

I cannot figure out how to add these 'recession shadings' in a `ListLinePlot`.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can include them as `Rectangle` objects in the `Prolog` of the plot:

```
ts = RandomReal[{-.6, 1.2}, 100];

ListLinePlot[
  ts,
  Prolog -> {GrayLevel[0.85],
    Rectangle[{1000, -100}, {2500, 100}],
    Rectangle[{5000, -100}, {5700, 100}]
  },
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using `Prolog` ensures that the plot is drawn on top of them, so they do not need to be transparent. Alternatively, if you do want transparency, you can control that by adding an `Opacity` directive after the color selection in the `Prolog`.

The top and bottom edges of the rectangles have been arbitrarily set to -100 and +100 in the code above; if that is not enough to make sure that the edges are well outside of the plot's range, they can be adjusted manually.

Answer (score 4):

```
data = RandomReal[{-6, 12}, 10];

{n, x} = Through[{Min, Max}[data]];

ListLinePlot[data,
 Prolog -> {LightGray, Rectangle[##] & @@@
    {{{2, n}, {4, x}},
     {{5, n}, {8, x}}}},
 Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Orange]
```

Or

```
ListLinePlot[{data,
  {{2, n}, {4, n}}, {{2, x}, {4, x}},
  {{5, n}, {8, n}}, {{5, x}, {8, x}}},
 Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Orange, None, None, None, None},
 Filling -> {{2 -> {{3}, LightGray}}, {4 -> {{5}, LightGray}}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[77777]
values = Accumulate /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {5, 300}];
```

### ListLinePlot

```
dates = Range@300;
data = Thread[{dates, #}] & /@ values;
recessions = {{20, 35}, {95, 120}, {180, 240}};
```

Combine two `ListLinePlot`s, one for the original time series and the second for `recessions`, using `Show`:

```
llp = ListLinePlot[ data];
llp2 = ListLinePlot[Thread[{#, PlotRange[llp][[2, 1]]}] & /@ recessions, 
   Filling -> Top, FillingStyle -> Opacity[.25, Gray], PlotStyle -> None, 
   PlotRange -> PlotRange[llp]];
Show[llp, llp2, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

### DateListPlot

```
dates = DateRange[{1990, 1}, DatePlus[{1990, 1}, {299, "Month"}], "Month"];
data = Thread[{dates, #}] & /@ values;
recessions = {{{1995, 1}, {1998, 2}}, {{2001, 2}, {2003, 1}}, {{2009, 5}, {2011, 2}}};
```

Combine two `DateListPlot`s, one for the original time series and the second for `recessions`, using `Show`:

```
dlp = DateListPlot[data,  Joined -> True];
dlp2 = DateListPlot[Thread[{#, PlotRange[dlp][[2, 1]]}] & /@ recessions, 
 Joined -> True, Filling -> Top, FillingStyle -> Opacity[.25, Gray], 
 PlotStyle -> None, PlotRange -> PlotRange[dlp]];
Show[dlp, dlp2]
```

[image]