# Plot shaded area from indicator variable

Tags: plotting, time-series, filling

I have downloaded some data from the Federal Reserve of St Louis:

```
fred = ServiceConnect["FederalReserveEconomicData"];

StartDate = "2000-01-01";
EndDate = "2022-12-01";

rate = fred["SeriesData", "ID" -> {"FEDFUNDS"}, "Date" -> {StartDate, EndDate}];
recession = fred["SeriesData", "ID" -> {"USREC"}, "Date" -> {StartDate, EndDate}];
```

Since you might not have access to the data, I provide a minimal subset of the data:

```
Normal[rate]
```

```
{{DateObject[{2007, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 5.02},{DateObject[{2007, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant","Gregorian", 0.], 4.94}, {DateObject[{2007, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 4.76}, {DateObject[{2007, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant","Gregorian", 0.], 4.49}, {DateObject[{2007, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0},"Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 4.24}, {DateObject[{2008, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant","Gregorian", 0.], 3.94}, {DateObject[{2008, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0},"Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 2.98}, {DateObject[{2008, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant","Gregorian", 0.], 2.61}, {DateObject[{2008, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0},"Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 2.28}, {DateObject[{2008, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant","Gregorian", 0.], 1.98}, {DateObject[{2008, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0},"Instant", "Gregorian", 0.], 2.}, {DateObject[{2008, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 2.01}, {DateObject[{2008, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant","Gregorian", 0.], 2.}, {DateObject[{2008, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 0.], 1.81}, {DateObject[{2008, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0},"Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 0.97}, {DateObject[{2008, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant","Gregorian", 0.], 0.39}, {DateObject[{2008, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0},"Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 0.16}, {DateObject[{2009, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant","Gregorian", 0.], 0.15}, {DateObject[{2009, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0},"Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 0.22}, {DateObject[{2009, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant","Gregorian", 0.], 0.18}, {DateObject[{2009, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0},"Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 0.15}, {DateObject[{2009, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant","Gregorian", 0.], 0.18}, {DateObject[{2009, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0},"Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 0.21}, {DateObject[{2009, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant","Gregorian", 0.], 0.16}, {DateObject[{2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0},"Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 0.16}, {DateObject[{2009, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant","Gregorian", 0.], 0.15}}
```

```
Normal[recession]
```

```
{{DateObject[{2007, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 0.}, {DateObject[{2007, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 0.}, {DateObject[{2007, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant","Gregorian", 0.], 0.}, {DateObject[{2007, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0},"Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 0.}, {DateObject[{2007, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant","Gregorian", 0.], 0.}, {DateObject[{2008, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 0.], 1.}, {DateObject[{2008, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0},"Instant", "Gregorian", 0.], 1.}, {DateObject[{2008, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 1.}, {DateObject[{2008, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 1.}, {DateObject[{2008, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant","Gregorian", 0.], 1.}, {DateObject[{2008, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 0.], 1.}, {DateObject[{2008, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0},"Instant", "Gregorian", 0.], 1.}, {DateObject[{2008, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 1.}, {DateObject[{2008, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 1.}, {DateObject[{2008, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant","Gregorian", 0.], 1.}, {DateObject[{2008, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0},"Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 1.}, {DateObject[{2008, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant","Gregorian", 0.], 1.}, {DateObject[{2009, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 0.], 1.}, {DateObject[{2009, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0},"Instant", "Gregorian", 0.], 1.}, {DateObject[{2009, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 1.}, {DateObject[{2009, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 1.}, {DateObject[{2009, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant","Gregorian", 0.], 1.}, {DateObject[{2009, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 0.], 1.}, {DateObject[{2009, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0},"Instant", "Gregorian", 0.], 0.}, {DateObject[{2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 0.}, {DateObject[{2009, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian",0.], 0.}}
```

As you can see, the variable `recession` has the same monthly frequency as the variable `rate` but only takes values in $\{0,1\}$.

Next, I plot the time series `rate`:

```
DateListPlot[{rate}]
```

[image]

I would like to add to this graph shaded regions corresponding to the points where `recession` takes the value of 1. More precisely, for the given sample data, I would expect the shaded region to start in January 2008 and finish in June 2009. But the procedure should be sufficiently general to produce another shaded area when the variable `recession` takes again the value of 1. How can I do it? I have attempted to follow this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172531/listlineplot-with-shading-areas) but it does not cover my case where the shaded region is dictated by an indicator variable.

Comment: Please provide (mock) data (or a minimal subset of the OP data) as access to the service requires credentials/API key.

Comment: I added a minimal subset of the data as suggested. I also added more details to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show another plot over the top with a `Filling`, hide the line, and use `InterpolationOrder -> 0` to prevent the line from sloping:

```
minrate = Min[rate[[All, 2]]];
Show[
 DateListPlot[TimeSeriesMap[# &, rate], PlotRange -> {minrate, 6}],
 DateListPlot[TimeSeriesMap[#*10 + minrate &, recession],
  Filling -> Bottom,
  PlotStyle -> None,
  InterpolationOrder -> 0]
 ]
```

[image: recessions]

Comment: Thanks. How can I make it fill the whole region up to the bottom axis? In other words, how can I remove the white space at the bottom?

Comment: @NC520 Add a PlotRange to the first plot so it becomes: `DateListPlot[rate, PlotRange -> {0, 5}],`

Comment: This doesn't work as expected because the series rates can become negative but the shaded region always starts at zero.

Comment: I should have asked a different question: how can I modify the code so that the shaded region is allowed to go below zero?

Comment: @NC520 you just need to add the minimum rate to deal with that. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

With `rate` and `recession` as defined in the OP, define a third plot as the one that will be used for `Filling`.

```
rdata = Select[
  Transpose[{rate[[All, 1]], rate[[All, 2]] recession[[All, 2]]}], 
  Last@# != 0 &]
```

Using `DateListStepPlot` and optionally changing the `PlotRange`:

```
DateListStepPlot[{rate, recession, rdata}, 
 PlotStyle -> {ColorData[97][1], ColorData[97][2], None}, 
 Filling -> {3 -> Bottom}, PlotRange -> {-2, 6}]
```

[image]